# Существует ли эквивалент Comparator.comparing из Java в NET?

Tags: java, c#

Помогите разобраться с данным кодом

```
 getAllMatchers()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Matcher::getSourceFileName).thenComparingLong(Matcher::getSourceFileLineNumber))
```

конкертно с последней строчкой, не могу понять, что значит `.thenComparingLong` и какой у нее есть (если есть) эквивалент в C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю что там в java, но компараторы в .NET есть, и возможности их широки, можно писать свои и использовать их в лямбда-функциях.

Предположительно что делает код, по порядку:

1. Берёт какой-то список элементов, пусть будет `List<Element>`
2. Пихает элемент в сортировщик с указанием корпаратора
3. Корпаратор работает на основе сравнения имён файлов элементов
4. Получает сортированные группы элементов на основе имён файлов по типу `Dictionary<string, List<Element>>`
5. Производит вторичную сортировку для второго параметра элемента Element getSourceFileLineNumber (где он его берёт - неизвестно, возможно это исходный номер элемента в неком списке)
6. На выходе сортированный `List<Element>`

Без понимания контекста, что там за данные (что за параметры getSourceFileLineNumber и getSourceFileName) на входе подробнее не скажешь.

В C# это можно реализовать следующим образом (даже без компаратора):

```
getAllMatchers()
   .OrderBy(y => y.getSourceFileName)
   .ThenBy(y => y.getSourceFileLineNumber)
```

Компараторы потребуются если мы хотим поменять принципы сравнения, или сравнить сложные параметры или уйти от комбинации OrderBy с ThenBy, чтобы использовать обычный Sort для класса целиком.

PS крайне полезная информация, если вам действительно потребуется компаратор https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.23.php